# Question in for using numpy "where" function

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

So I am trying to learn python and some stats. In one example code about the F-test, this appears.

```
np.random.seed(12)

# Generate random data

voter_race = np.random.choice(a= races, p = [0.05, 0.15 ,0.25, 0.05, 0.5], size=1000)



# Use a different distribution for white ages

white_ages = stats.poisson.rvs(loc=18, mu=32, size=1000)

voter_age = stats.poisson.rvs(loc=18, mu=30, size=1000)

voter_age = np.where(voter_race=="white", white_ages, voter_age)


# Group age data by race

voter_frame = pd.DataFrame({"race":voter_race,"age":voter_age})

groups = voter_frame.groupby("race").groups


# Extract individual groups

asian = voter_age[groups["asian"]]

black = voter_age[groups["black"]]

hispanic = voter_age[groups["hispanic"]]

other = voter_age[groups["other"]]

white = voter_age[groups["white"]]


# Perform the ANOVA

stats.f_oneway(asian, black, hispanic, other, white)
```

In the bolded code, why does `voter_race` appear twice, and why is `white_ages` also in the `np.where` code?

Answer (score 0):

np.where returns x or y, (the second or third parameter) depending on if the first parameter condition is true or not. If the condition is true return x otherwise return y. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on that function is pretty good.

So the np.where statement here will return white_ages if voter_race is "white" otherwise it will return voter_age.

Also none of your code appears bolded, FYI.

Comment: My bad. I first posted this on reddit where I bolded the text, but because I got no reply, I copied it on here, and thus the bolded code disappeared. But thanks anyways!